# Getting expected to return a value at the end of the arrow function error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have a function like this,
[image]

```
  const isDisplayStaticAndConditionalSwitcher = (fieldNode, window) => {
    const fieldDataSourceCode = fieldNode.getAttribute('DataSourceCode') || [];
    const nodeValues = Object.values(window?.Designer?.nodes); // get the nodes values 
     
    const formDataSourceCode = nodeValues.map((o) => {
      if (o.displayName === 'Form') { return o.props.code; } 
    }).filter((v) => v)[0];

    return fieldDataSourceCode === formDataSourceCode;
  };
```

I am getting the error, `expected to return a value at the end of the arrow function error`  How should I resolve the issue?

Comment: It's not an error, it's a linter warning. Did you read the explanation of the linting rule you are using?

Comment: You'll probably want to write `nodeValues.find(o => o.displayName === 'Form')?.props.code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lint rules want you to explicitly return undefined:

```
nodeValues.map((o) => {
  if (o.displayName === "Form") {
    return o.props.code;
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The lint error is because of `if` condition inside `map` function. you need to return the same value or other in case of if condition fails.

Using map, Expectation from map function to return same length of Array.

```
const formDataSourceCode = nodeValues.map((o) => {
      if (o.displayName === 'Form') { return o.props.code; }  
      // add the return in case if condition fails.
      return o;
    }).filter((v) => v)[0];
```

Hope this is helpful.